# RAM upgrade options for a first generation 15" MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, unibody

I am working on one of the first 15" Unibody MacBook Pro's (Late 2008 - MB470LL/A - MacBookPro5,1).

According to [EveryMac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2.4-aluminum-15-late-2008-unibody-specs.html) (and other sources), this machine really only supports 4GB of RAM. It looks like higher may work, but unsure.

The machine is base with 2GB of RAM, 2 x 1GB chips. I would like to upgrade the RAM in this, but unsure of what path to take.

- Can you just purchase one 4GB stick and it be ok?
- What happens to these machines when you put 8GB in them?
- Does anyone actually sell 2x2GB chips anymore? Looking quickly on newegg I did not find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have upgraded the RAM to 8GB for my MBP470.  See the config below.  No problem happened. Be noticed that, 470 only support 1066MHz DDR3 RAM.  Do not use 1333MHz RAM. The 8GB RAM is from Sumsung.

[image]

Comment: Does it address all 8GB? Do you have any stability issues? Was it ever documented to fully support 8GB?

Comment: Didn't find any official documented 8GB is supported.  So far didn't find any stability issues, upgraded for more than 1 year.

Comment: Did you ever have to install a new firmware, etc to get this to work?

Comment: After doing some research, it looks like this machines only had an issue with a certain version of Snow Leopard or below (these machines shipped with Leopard). From everything I have read, it should be fine after a firmware update.